# Next js query is not given actually result

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I learning next js(typescript) and i created functino getServerSideProps({query}) in detail/[slug].tsx but the query aren't given actually result in url

in url localhost:3000/detail/samsung-s23?variant=black but in getServerSideProps() i'll got

```
query:{
  slug:'wow',
}
```

I try to hardcode with slug= samsung-23 but it will replaced by 'wow',

Iam still using dummy data

here my code

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  console.log('request', query)
  // here function for search slug to item product 

  return {
    props: {
      slug: 'Samsung-s23-ram-8',
    },
  }
}
```

```
const Detail = ({ slug }) => {
 console.log(slug)
  const id = 'asddwases126'

  return (
    <PDPFullLayouts>
      <ProductDetails
        productId={id}
        detailProduct={dataDetail.detailProducts}
      />
      <PopularProducts />
    </PDPFullLayouts>
  )
}
```

in my question is how to change my slug from request not given `wow` again?.

Answer (score 0):

To get a dynamic route param in getServerSideProps method, you have to access to req.params.

Docs:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter